# Need to know when a scentences end with own code, can't compare two array values. in C

Tags: arrays, c, char, initialization, string-literals

So i just started coding with C and want to wake a program to know how many sentences there are in a text. However when making an array with a ".", "?" and "!" I get an error when comparing them to my text[i].

My code is as follows:

```
int main(void)
{
string text = "Hi there, i'm walking through the woods. Oh there is a branch, i need to jump over. I hope i don't fall.";
printf("%c \n", text[39]); // is a "."
printf("%c \n", text[82]); // is a "."
printf("%c \n", text[103]); // is a "."
printf("%c \n", text[-1]); // i would expect a "." here, but it doesn't show when executing the program. (total of 3 sentences)

char scanend[3] = {".", "?", "!"};
int sentences = 0;
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
{
  if (text[i] == scanend[0] || text[i] == scanend[1] || text[i] == scanend[2])
  {
      sentences++;
  }
}
printf("%i\n", sentences);
}
```

Why do I get an error when comparing these two array's? and how can i compare them without an error?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: "i would expect a "."" C is not python (etc). It is nonsensical to access the -1-th element of an array: this is just whatever happens to be in the memory preceding the first element of the array.

Comment: What is `string`? (Is this cs50?) And, whatever, `char scanend[3] = {".", "?", "!"};` is wrong and should be `char scanend[3] = {'.', '?', '!'};`.

Comment: Does your compiler has some opinion on your initialization of `scanend` array? Isn't there some warning?

Comment: CodeLearner,  "when comparing these two array's?" --> Code like `text[i] == scanend[0]` is not comparing arrays.  Code is comparing 2 `char`.   A `char` is not an _array_.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the name `string` is declared as a typedef name for `char *`. Otherwise you need to declare the variable `text` as having the type `char *` or `const char *`.

The initializer list in this declaration

```
char scanend[3] = {".", "?", "!"};
```

is incorrect. You are trying to initialize objects of the type char with pointers of the type char * to which string literals are implicitly converted.

Either write

```
char scanend[3] = {".?!"};
```

or

```
char scanend[3] = {'.', '?', '!'};
```

However it would be better to declare the array like

```
char scanend[] = {".?!"};
```

and instead of this if statement

```
if (text[i] == scanend[0] || text[i] == scanend[1] || text[i] == scanend[2])
{
    sentences++;
}
```

to write

```
if ( strchr( scanend, text[i] ) != NULL )
{
    sentences++;
}
```

Pay attention to that the expression text[-1] used in this call

```
printf("%c \n", text[-1]);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Instead you could write

```
printf("%c \n", text[strlen( text ) - 1]);
```

Also the return type of the function `strlen` is `size_t`. So the for loop should look like

```
for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
```